# Can both direct and indirect and total effect become negative in mediation

Tags: mediation

I am doing my research on perceived stress and happiness mediation effect of meaning in life. My results showed direct indirect and total effect as negative. Only b path is positive. Please help me is it OK or flawed?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I would rather wait to answer your question when you've edited the question to be more clear. You need to provide more information.

However, based on what you've said, I don't see anything wrong. You can have a negative direct effect, a negative indirect effect, and a negative total effect.